# Download custom Google Analytics Report using Python

Tags: python, csv, google-analytics

Is there a way to download a custom Google Analytics report (as a CSV) using the Python API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No the API does not allow to download custom reports but i ll let you query with all the same parameters you create your report so i don't see how that would be different. I ll take the chance to leave you with documentation and a really good post to query GA data:

Query with python: http://www.ryanpraski.com/python-google-analytics-api-unsampled-data-multiple-profiles/

Docs: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/

Comment: Hi @Marco. Does API allows to download saved reports?